# Microsoft Access - Decimal Scale stuck at 0

Tags: ms-access, decimal, ms-access-2010, rounding

I have a calculated field in my table called C. its the result of A-B=C. A & B are number fields (single, fixed). I have having trouble setting up C as a calculated (Decimal Field).

The precision / decimal places seem to work perfectly, I can modify them freely. But no matter what I do to "SCALE". It always seems to return to "0". I need it to be 2 since all my data in my reports are rounding off at the wrong locations giving me hole numbers.

[image]

As you can see "scale = 0", no matter what I do to this number. it will always revert to "0". Why is that?

Comment: You've failed to include how you're defining the DECIMAL field.

Comment: @KenWhite I added a photo in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t change the scale in a calculated field, because it takes the values and settings from the calculation.

So the fact of a scale of 0 should not matter. The resulting number if it needs decimal places will (should) have the decimal value. The setting is IGNORED

I mean, if the calculation is:

2 x 3 = 6

Then you get 6.

If you have 4 / 3 = 1.3333

Then, in your case you get:

1.33333333333333

And you WILL get the above EVEN if the scale = 0. So the scale setting is NOT used nor available in a calculated field.

You are certainly free to round, or format the above result. And in fact you could (should) consider using the round() function in the actual calculation. So use something like:

Round([Field1] / [Field2],4)

And you thus get:

1.3333